# Interpn - changing output

Tags: matlab, performance, vectorization, interpolation

I have 4 grids:

1. `kgrid` which is [77x1]
2. `x` which is [15x1]
3. `z` which is [9x1]
4. `s` which is [2x1]

Then I have a function:

5. `kprime` which is [77x15x9x2]

I want to interpolate `kprime` at some points `ksim (750 x 1)` and `zsim (750 x 1)` (`xsim` is a scalar). I am doing:

```
[ks, xs, zs, ss] = ndgrid(kgrid, x, z, [1;2]);
Output = interpn(ks, xs, zs, ss, kprime, ksim, xsim, zsim, 1,'linear');
```

The problem with this interpolation is that the output given is for all combinations of `ksim` and `zsim`, meaning that the output is 750x750. I actually need an output of 750x1, meaning that instead of interpolation at all combinations of `ksim` and `zsim` I only need to interpolate at `ksim(1,1)` and `zsim(1,1)`, then `ksim(2,1)` and `zsim(2,1)`, then `ksim(3,1)` and `zsim(3,1)`, etc.

In other words, after getting `Output` I am doing:

```
Output = diag(squeeze(Output));
```

I know I can use this output and then just pick the numbers I want, but this is extremely inefficient as it actually interpolates on all other points which I actually do not need. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample inputs so that we can actually run your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Change `xsim` and (`ssim`) from scalars to vectors of the same size as `ksim` and `zsim`

```
Output = interpn (ks, xs, zs, ss,           ...
                  kprime,                   ...
                  ksim,                     ...
                  repmat(xsim, size(ksim)), ... % <-- here
                  zsim,                     ...
                  repmat(1, size(ksim)),    ... % <-- and here
                  'linear');
```

---

**Explanation:**

The `ksim`, `xsim`, `zsim`, and `ssim` inputs all need to have the same shape, so that at each common position in that shape, each input acts as an "interpolated subscript" component to the interpolated object. Note that while they all need to have the same shape, this shape can be arbitrary in terms of size and dimensions.

Conversely, if you pass *vectors* of different sizes (after all, a scalar is a vector of length 1), these get interpreted as the *components of an ndgrid construction instead*. So you were actually telling `interpn` to evaluate all interpolations on a grid defined by the vectors `ksim`, and `zsim` (and your singletons `xsim` and `ssim`). Which is why you got a 2D-grid-looking output.

---

Note that the same scheme applies with the *constructing* vectors as well (i.e. ks, xs, zs and ss) i.e. you could have used "vector syntax" instead of "common shape" syntax to define the grid instead, i.e.

```
Output = interpn(kgrid, x, z, s, kprime, % ...etc etc
```

and you would have gotten the same result.

Comment: Well, this probably turned sour for no reason. To be honest I did read the documentation very carefully and did not fulyl get it. @TasosPapastylianou answer helped me much more than tvo. tvo did not tell me anything I had not read yet.

Comment: Sorry I lost my temper last night, re-reading this I think I was on quite a short fuse :/  Glad you found it useful volcompt.

Comment: I think that all this series of comments can be deleted, they do not contribute anything for this post. However, congrats Tasos, you recognized right what was missig for the OP.

Comment: @volcompt If you would have replied to the comments by me and EBH on my answer, we could have helped you two days ago. There's no need to start complaining about that now. This answer is essentially the same solution as mine, but admittedly easier to apply (because it has _the code_). From your comments, it was clear you know about the use of `repmat`, so you had all the ingredients. Next time, if something's not clear, just say why. You'll find it easier to get help... And be respectful to the people who try to help you.

Comment: @tvo, I agree, and apologies for my silence but I had a family emergency which precluded my from checking stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5):

### From the [documents](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interpn.html#inputarg_Xq1Xq2Xqn):

> Query points, specified as a real scalars, vectors, or arrays.
>
> - If Xq1,Xq2,...,Xqn are scalars, then they are the coordinates of a single query point in Rn.
> - If Xq1,Xq2,...,Xqn are vectors of different orientations, then Xq1,Xq2,...,Xqn are treated as grid vectors in Rn.
> - **If Xq1,Xq2,...,Xqn are vectors of the same size and orientation, then Xq1,Xq2,...,Xqn are treated as scattered points in Rn.**
> - If Xq1,Xq2,...,Xqn are arrays of the same size, then they represent either a full grid of query points (in ndgrid format) or scattered points in Rn.

### Answer

You want the usage highlighted in bold. As such, you have to **make sure that `xsim` and `ssim` ('1' in your code sample) are of size `750x1` also**. Then all the query vectors are same length and orientation, such that it can be recognized as a vector of scattered points in Rn. The output will then be a `750x1` vector as needed.

Comment: Yes, the issue is that indeed xsim is a scalar and not a vector. I can use repmat to repeat it several times but I do not think that's what I need.

Comment: @volcompt You also have to do it for the second-to-last argument in your code sample: '1'. Then the output will be a 750x1 vector, and there is no more need to remove any interpolated data. This is what you want right? Otherwise, you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @volcompt this answer is quite straightforward. For `xsim` and all other scalars, don't use `repmat` but [repelem](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html?searchHighlight=repelem) or simply multiply them by `vec` where `vec` is predifined as `vec = ones(750,1)`.

Comment: @EBH what is the advantage of `repelem` or multiplying with `ones` over `repmat`? Is it faster, if so why?

Comment: @tvo See my answer here

Answer (score 4):

This is to elaborate on @tvo/@Tasos answers, to test the fastest way to create a vector from a scalar:

```
function create_vector(n)
x = 5;
repm_time = timeit(@()repm(x,n))
repe_time = timeit(@()repe(x,n))
vrep_time = timeit(@()vrep(x,n))
onesv_time = timeit(@()onesv(x,n))
end

function A = repm(x,n)
for k = 1:10000
    A = repmat(x,[n 1]);
end
end

function A = repe(x,n)
for k = 1:10000
    A = repelem(x,n).';
end
end

function A = vrep(x,n)
v = ones(n,1);
for k = 1:10000
    A = x*v;
end
end

function A = onesv(x,n)
for k = 1:10000
    A = x*ones(n,1);
end
end
```

And the results are (for `n = 750`):

```
repm_time =
     0.049847
repe_time =
     0.044188
vrep_time =
    0.0041342
onesv_time =
    0.0024869
```

which means that the fastest way to create a vector from a scalar is simply writing `x*ones(n,1)`.

Comment: Interesting, just a slight difference between `repmat` and `repelem`, but an order of magnitude faster with `ones`. Also the difference between 3 and 4 is remarkable, and counterintuitive.

Comment: I was mostly surprised by that `*` operator by itself (`vrep`) takes more time then calling it with `ones` (`onesv`).

Comment: You mean that 0.0041342 > 0.0024869, right? The former is dominated by the multiplication I assume. The latter is a combination of multiplying with executing ones(n,1). My guess is that Matlab optimizes `x*ones`-type expressions, where `x*v` requires 'full' matrix multiplication.